# LS factor for RUSLE

Tags: arcgis-desktop, rusle

I am working to estimate soil loss, and for that I am using the RUSLE model. Now I am preparing the LS factor using:

```
LS=(flow*cell size/22.1)m * (sin slope x 0.01745/0.0896)1.3
```

The raster command that I have used was:

```
Power("wateshed_acc" * 30 / 22.1,0.4) * Power(Sin("slope_deg") * 0.01745 / 0.0896,1.3)
```

But there are many no data values. Thus, how can I avoid those no data values? Additionally, what is the recommended command for raster calculator? I am using Arc GIS 10.2.2.

Comment: Is the issue that these no data values are resulting in a raster which is smaller than the original? You looking to assign a constant to these no data areas so that the calf will cover your study area?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Power("wateshed_acc" * 30 / 22.1,0.4) * Power(Sin("slope_deg" * 0.01745) / 0.0896,1.3)
```

Only change is the location of the right parenthesis for the degrees to radians conversion.

Add also confirm that "watershed_acc" is your flow accumulation raster  with a resolution of 30.  I would think you would get no data in some areas unless all your rasters have data every where.